# Different date is being uploaded in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a form to upload some type of data. Where I also want to upload the date and time of upload.
I have written this code in php :

```
$date=date("d-m-Y h:i:s A"); //this is date format
INSERT INTO `form_table`(`category`, `title`, `description`, `image`, `article`, `date`) VALUES ('$category','$title','$description','$image','$article','$date');
```

But this code inserts wrong time into database. For example if I'm uploading data at **21-01-2020 10:50:00 pm**, the date and time uploaded into database is **21-01-2020 6:50:00 pm** which is a wrong time.

Comment: MySQL prefers `Y-m-d` as the date format. Though this sounds like a timezone mismatch. You might want to check the timezone for both PHP and MySQL/system.

Comment: Thanks anyber for quick responce, I have also used that but still wrong date is being inserted.

Comment: Again, this sounds like a timezone issue in your mysql configuration.  What is the type of the `date` column?

Comment: As mentioned, check the timezone set in PHP on the server. The server has no way to know the timezone for your local PC. So, you have to manually set it on the server. Then, it will work for your PC - but not for a PC in another timezone.

Comment: @AlexBarker Barker I am storing time in just text format.

Comment: @kainaw I think your suggestion will work, but I don't know how to do that. Can you tell me the procedure to set timezone manually.

Comment: @AftabAnsari What kind of server are you using? Windows? Linux? Mac? Commodore 64? Most people use some form of Linux and the PHP setup is commonly in /etc/php.ini. In there is a setting for the timezeone. Type in the timezone you want.

Comment: If date is just a text field, your date.timezone setting in the php.ini file is not set to what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
echo(date("Y-m-d h:i:s:A"));